# Error:Command \dj unavailable in encoding OT1

Tags: babel

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnam]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\centering
\textbf{\huge 12 Shigatsu wa Kimi no Uso}
\begin{spacing}{2.0}
\begin{enumerate}
    \renewcommand
        {\theenumi}
        {\Roman{enumi}}
    \item Thần đồng piano Kōsei Arima thống trị các giải đấu và trở nên nổi tiếng trong giới âm nhạc. Sau cái chết của mẹ, đồng thời là người dạy piano cho cậu, cậu bị suy nhược thần kinh trong một cuộc thi khi mới 11 tuổi. Sau đó, cậu không thể nghe tiếng đàn do chính mình đánh dù cậu không có vấn đề khác về thính giác. Hai năm trôi qua, Kōsei không hề chạm vào cây đàn và nhìn thế giới qua cái nhìn đơn sắc. Cậu tự giải nghệ và bước tiếp cùng với những người bạn tốt, Tsubaki và Watari, cho tới một ngày, một cô gái đã thay đổi tất cả. Kaori Miyazono, một nữ sinh cùng lớp với Tsubaki, 14 tuổi, một nhạc công violin với thiên hướng tự do để những nốt nhạc phản ảnh bản thân, giúp Kōsei trở lại với thế giới âm nhạc và cho cậu thấy nó là cả thế giới tự do mà không gò bó như cách cậu từng chơi.
    \item Kōsei là mấy thần đồng piano, được đặt cho biệt danh "Máy đo nhịp hình nhân" vì sự chính xác gần như tuyệt đối khi biểu diễn, là kết quả của phương pháp dạy dỗ nghiêm khắc của mẹ cậu. Khả năng chơi đàn của cậu giúp cậu tham gia vào nhiều cuộc thi trên khắp Nhật Bản. Cái chết của mẹ để lại di chấn tâm tâm lý nặng nề đối với cậu khiến cho cậu không thể nghe được tiếng đàn do chính mình tạo ra. Giờ đây, hai năm sau, cậu bắt đầu tập đàn trở lại sau khi bị thuyết phục bởi Kaori Miyazono, và bị ảnh hưởng bởi phong cách chơi nhạc tự do và phóng túng của cô. Kōsei cuối cùng thích Kaori nhưng không dám thổ lộ vì cô tuyên bố rằng cô thích Watari. Sau khi Kaori qua đời, Kōsei đã nhận ra rằng Kaori mang nặng tình cảm với cậu qua bức thư cuối cùng do cô viết ra.
    \item Kaori là bạn cùng lớp của Tsubaki, và là một nghệ sĩ violin có thiên hướng tự do, người nhận được nhiều lời phê bình từ các hội đồng giám khảo do sự thiếu tôn trọng bản nhạc và cách tính điểm, nhưng lại được nhiều sự ủng hộ từ khán giả. Kaori lần đầu gặp Kōsei khi cô nhờ Tsubaki sắp đặt cuộc hẹn đôi với Watari, và thuyết phục được Kōsei chơi piano trở lại, lần đầu tiên là với tư cách người đệm đàn cho cô ở một cuộc thi. Kaori từ nhỏ đã muốn được chơi dương cầm (piano) nhưng cô đã chuyển sang chơi vĩ cầm (violin) vì cô muốn Kōsei là người đánh đàn cho mình sau khi nghe cậu bé chơi piano trong cuộc thi dương cầm lúc 5 tuổi. Và tình cảm của cô dành cho Kōsei bắt đầu từ đó. Tuy nhiên, khi lần đầu gặp lại Kōseii ở trung học, cô đã nói dối với Kōsei rằng cô thích Ryouta Watari để cô có thể tiếp xúc nhiều hơn với Kōsei.
    \renewcommand
    {\labelenumi}
    {\theenumi}
  \item Tsubaki Sawabe \footnote {Bạn thân từ thuở nhỏ của Kōsei và đồng thời là hàng xóm, người coi cậu như đứa em trai bướng bỉnh. Cô là người thích vận động và tham gia đội tuyển bóng chày của trường. Thường nghi ngờ về khả năng vượt qua nỗi đau của Kōsei, cô tìm cách để lôi kéo cậu chơi piano lần nữa. Cô chối rằng mình không có tính cảm hơn cả bạn bè với Kōsei nhưng sau đó thừa nhận.}
\end{enumerate}
\raggedleft
Nguồn:
\href{https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shigatsu_wa_Kimi_no_Uso}{wikipedia.org}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Error:Command \dj unavailable in encoding OT1.
Pls help me :(

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I only get an error with the `vietnam` option, which should be `vietnamese`.

Answer (score 4):

With `vietnamese` as option for babel, you example compiles just fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\centering
\textbf{\huge 12 Shigatsu wa Kimi no Uso}
\begin{spacing}{2.0}
\begin{enumerate}
    \renewcommand
        {\theenumi}
        {\Roman{enumi}}
    \item Thần đồng piano Kōsei Arima thống trị các giải đấu và trở nên nổi tiếng trong giới âm nhạc. Sau cái chết của mẹ, đồng thời là người dạy piano cho cậu, cậu bị suy nhược thần kinh trong một cuộc thi khi mới 11 tuổi. Sau đó, cậu không thể nghe tiếng đàn do chính mình đánh dù cậu không có vấn đề khác về thính giác. Hai năm trôi qua, Kōsei không hề chạm vào cây đàn và nhìn thế giới qua cái nhìn đơn sắc. Cậu tự giải nghệ và bước tiếp cùng với những người bạn tốt, Tsubaki và Watari, cho tới một ngày, một cô gái đã thay đổi tất cả. Kaori Miyazono, một nữ sinh cùng lớp với Tsubaki, 14 tuổi, một nhạc công violin với thiên hướng tự do để những nốt nhạc phản ảnh bản thân, giúp Kōsei trở lại với thế giới âm nhạc và cho cậu thấy nó là cả thế giới tự do mà không gò bó như cách cậu từng chơi.
    \item Kōsei là mấy thần đồng piano, được đặt cho biệt danh "Máy đo nhịp hình nhân" vì sự chính xác gần như tuyệt đối khi biểu diễn, là kết quả của phương pháp dạy dỗ nghiêm khắc của mẹ cậu. Khả năng chơi đàn của cậu giúp cậu tham gia vào nhiều cuộc thi trên khắp Nhật Bản. Cái chết của mẹ để lại di chấn tâm tâm lý nặng nề đối với cậu khiến cho cậu không thể nghe được tiếng đàn do chính mình tạo ra. Giờ đây, hai năm sau, cậu bắt đầu tập đàn trở lại sau khi bị thuyết phục bởi Kaori Miyazono, và bị ảnh hưởng bởi phong cách chơi nhạc tự do và phóng túng của cô. Kōsei cuối cùng thích Kaori nhưng không dám thổ lộ vì cô tuyên bố rằng cô thích Watari. Sau khi Kaori qua đời, Kōsei đã nhận ra rằng Kaori mang nặng tình cảm với cậu qua bức thư cuối cùng do cô viết ra.
    \item Kaori là bạn cùng lớp của Tsubaki, và là một nghệ sĩ violin có thiên hướng tự do, người nhận được nhiều lời phê bình từ các hội đồng giám khảo do sự thiếu tôn trọng bản nhạc và cách tính điểm, nhưng lại được nhiều sự ủng hộ từ khán giả. Kaori lần đầu gặp Kōsei khi cô nhờ Tsubaki sắp đặt cuộc hẹn đôi với Watari, và thuyết phục được Kōsei chơi piano trở lại, lần đầu tiên là với tư cách người đệm đàn cho cô ở một cuộc thi. Kaori từ nhỏ đã muốn được chơi dương cầm (piano) nhưng cô đã chuyển sang chơi vĩ cầm (violin) vì cô muốn Kōsei là người đánh đàn cho mình sau khi nghe cậu bé chơi piano trong cuộc thi dương cầm lúc 5 tuổi. Và tình cảm của cô dành cho Kōsei bắt đầu từ đó. Tuy nhiên, khi lần đầu gặp lại Kōseii ở trung học, cô đã nói dối với Kōsei rằng cô thích Ryouta Watari để cô có thể tiếp xúc nhiều hơn với Kōsei.
    \renewcommand
    {\labelenumi}
    {\theenumi}
  \item Tsubaki Sawabe \footnote {Bạn thân từ thuở nhỏ của Kōsei và đồng thời là hàng xóm, người coi cậu như đứa em trai bướng bỉnh. Cô là người thích vận động và tham gia đội tuyển bóng chày của trường. Thường nghi ngờ về khả năng vượt qua nỗi đau của Kōsei, cô tìm cách để lôi kéo cậu chơi piano lần nữa. Cô chối rằng mình không có tính cảm hơn cả bạn bè với Kōsei nhưng sau đó thừa nhận.}
\end{enumerate}
\raggedleft
Nguồn:
\href{https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shigatsu_wa_Kimi_no_Uso}{wikipedia.org}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tks you so much ^^

Comment: @TúNguyễn Good to hear that the answer helped you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing between

```
\usepackage{vietnam}
```

and

```
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
```

They are alternative ways for typesetting Vietnamese texts. Here's the version with the former.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{vietnam}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\huge\bfseries
12 Shigatsu wa Kimi no Uso
\end{center}

\doublespacing

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]

\item Thần đồng piano Kōsei Arima thống trị các giải 
đấu và trở nên nổi tiếng trong giới âm nhạc. Sau cái 
chết của mẹ, đồng thời là người dạy piano cho cậu, cậu 
bị suy nhược thần kinh trong một cuộc thi khi mới 11 tuổi. 
Sau đó, cậu không thể nghe tiếng đàn do chính mình đánh 
dù cậu không có vấn đề khác về thính giác. Hai năm trôi 
qua, Kōsei không hề chạm vào cây đàn và nhìn thế giới qua 
cái nhìn đơn sắc. Cậu tự giải nghệ và bước tiếp cùng với 
những người bạn tốt, Tsubaki và Watari, cho tới một ngày, 
một cô gái đã thay đổi tất cả. Kaori Miyazono, một nữ sinh 
cùng lớp với Tsubaki, 14 tuổi, một nhạc công violin với 
thiên hướng tự do để những nốt nhạc phản ảnh bản thân, 
giúp Kōsei trở lại với thế giới âm nhạc và cho cậu thấy 
nó là cả thế giới tự do mà không gò bó như cách cậu từng chơi.

\item Kōsei là mấy thần đồng piano, được đặt cho biệt danh 
``Máy đo nhịp hình nhân'' vì sự chính xác gần như tuyệt đối 
khi biểu diễn, là kết quả của phương pháp dạy dỗ nghiêm khắc 
của mẹ cậu. Khả năng chơi đàn của cậu giúp cậu tham gia vào 
nhiều cuộc thi trên khắp Nhật Bản. Cái chết của mẹ để lại di 
chấn tâm tâm lý nặng nề đối với cậu khiến cho cậu không thể 
nghe được tiếng đàn do chính mình tạo ra. Giờ đây, hai năm 
sau, cậu bắt đầu tập đàn trở lại sau khi bị thuyết phục bởi 
Kaori Miyazono, và bị ảnh hưởng bởi phong cách chơi nhạc tự 
do và phóng túng của cô. Kōsei cuối cùng thích Kaori nhưng 
không dám thổ lộ vì cô tuyên bố rằng cô thích Watari. Sau 
khi Kaori qua đời, Kōsei đã nhận ra rằng Kaori mang nặng 
tình cảm với cậu qua bức thư cuối cùng do cô viết ra.

\item Kaori là bạn cùng lớp của Tsubaki, và là một nghệ sĩ 
violin có thiên hướng tự do, người nhận được nhiều lời phê 
bình từ các hội đồng giám khảo do sự thiếu tôn trọng bản nhạc 
và cách tính điểm, nhưng lại được nhiều sự ủng hộ từ khán giả. 
Kaori lần đầu gặp Kōsei khi cô nhờ Tsubaki sắp đặt cuộc hẹn 
đôi với Watari, và thuyết phục được Kōsei chơi piano trở lại, 
lần đầu tiên là với tư cách người đệm đàn cho cô ở một cuộc 
thi. Kaori từ nhỏ đã muốn được chơi dương cầm (piano) nhưng 
cô đã chuyển sang chơi vĩ cầm (violin) vì cô muốn Kōsei là 
người đánh đàn cho mình sau khi nghe cậu bé chơi piano trong 
cuộc thi dương cầm lúc 5 tuổi. Và tình cảm của cô dành cho 
Kōsei bắt đầu từ đó. Tuy nhiên, khi lần đầu gặp lại Kōseii 
ở trung học, cô đã nói dối với Kōsei rằng cô thích Ryouta 
Watari để cô có thể tiếp xúc nhiều hơn với Kōsei.

\item Tsubaki Sawabe \footnote {Bạn thân từ thuở nhỏ của 
Kōsei và đồng thời là hàng xóm, người coi cậu như đứa em 
trai bướng bỉnh. Cô là người thích vận động và tham gia 
đội tuyển bóng chày của trường. Thường nghi ngờ về khả năng 
vượt qua nỗi đau của Kōsei, cô tìm cách để lôi kéo cậu chơi 
piano lần nữa. Cô chối rằng mình không có tính cảm hơn cả 
bạn bè với Kōsei nhưng sau đó thừa nhận.}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{flushright}
Nguồn:
\href{https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shigatsu_wa_Kimi_no_Uso}{wikipedia.org}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

I made also some fixes.

1. Use `enumitem` for customizing the `enumerate` environment
2. Use `\doublespacing` rather than the `spacing` environment (which clashes with `hyperref` when the footnote is processed)
3. Use ``` `` ``` and `''` for the quotation marks
4. Never use `\centering` and `\raggedright` at the outer level

[image]